# Loading Pytorch weights results in poor performance compared to training

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm currently messing around PPO reinforcement learning with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlv79rcHws0) (Github code located [here](https://github.com/philtabor/Youtube-Code-Repository/tree/master/ReinforcementLearning/PolicyGradient/PPO/torch)). The training goes well and the model seems to be able to learn how to keep the pole up, but when I load the model it performs as if it was just initialized to random weights. The time stamp of the file corresponds to when it was last saved, so I'm definitely overwriting the checkpoint file with the most recent version of the networks.

My inference.py file is as follows:

```py
import gym
import numpy as np
from ppo_torch import Agent
import time
import sys

env = gym.make('CartPole-v1', render_mode = "human")

batch_size = 16
n_epochs = 5
alpha = 0.0003

agent = Agent(n_actions=env.action_space.n, batch_size=batch_size, 
                    alpha=alpha, n_epochs=n_epochs, 
                    input_dims=env.observation_space.shape)

agent.load_models()
agent.critic.eval()
agent.actor.eval()

while True:
    observation, _ = env.reset()
    done = False
    while not done:
        start = time.time()
        action, prob, val = agent.choose_action(observation)
        observation_, reward, done, info, _ = env.step(action)

        env.render()
        end = time.time()
        print(f'{(1/(end-start)):.2f}', end="\r", flush=True)
```

The only change I've made was adding a ".pth" to the `self.checkpoint_file` in both ActorNetwork and CriticNetwork. So the Actor and Critic `self.checkpoint_file` path is:

```py
self.checkpoint_file = os.path.join(chkpt_dir, 'actor_torch_ppo.pth')
#...
self.checkpoint_file = os.path.join(chkpt_dir, 'critic_torch_ppo.pth')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I wasn't actually taking the observation after taking a step in the environment:

```py
observation_, reward, done, info, _ = env.step(action)
```

Notice how I get **observation_** but then still use **observation** to get the next action:

```py
action, prob, val = agent.choose_action(observation)
```

which was the initial observation made when the environment was reset. I fixed this issue and it's now working as intended.